# Imported OBJ file with transparent texture has black background

Tags: texturing, materials, color, obj

When I import OBJ file with texture image of transparent png and red background I can see the color of red is correct when in Solid Preview mode.

But once I switch to material or rendered preview mode where I would expect to see the image with red bg all I see is the image with pitch black bg - why?

In fact I am just testing if the OBJ file is OK (it is OBJ I made, generated by the Blender 2.8), cos it does not show texture in UE4 where I want to use it (so now I know the info about the texture is correct and something else is wrong with the UE4, but that is another topic, of course).

PS: I would like to have a solution without using of NODES, if possible.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: it is not a .blend file, it is ".obj + .mtl + transparent .png" that opened in Blender (via import .obj) does not show the red bg color of the brick. Instead it is showing the image of the png (which has transparent bg) with pitch black bg and that s my problem as I do not know why is that...so I uploaded those 3 file to Zippyshare here: [link](https://www114.zippyshare.com/v/WxGNWnqY/file.html). BTW that obj file was created INSIDE BLENDER, so maybe I could also add that .blend file after all, so here it is: [link](https://www1.zippyshare.com/v/EZXb9L6W/file.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : So my answer only answers partially to your problem, whoever knows a bit better about Obj and Mtl imports will hopefully give you a better answer.

I don't know how to work without nodes, so I show you the problem and the solution with the nodes:

- You want your arrow to show up on your object on a red background, here is the current node organization:

[image]

- This node organization doesn't allow you to show any background, so it shows only black where there's the alpha transparency. The red you see in *Solid* mode is actually the color you've picked as *Viewport Display* color:

[image]

- To create a red background, you have several solutions, you can plug your *Image Texure* into a *MixRGB*, choose a red color in the second socket, and plug the *Image Texture* alpha output into the factor of the *MixRGB*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But there is red specified in the mtl file for the obj, thus that red color comes from the obj.

Comment: edit: mh ok seems like the mtl file contains the material informations, except that it doesn't seem to work the way you want, see the node organization I've sreenshot

Comment: ah, so you cannot help me with this one as it is probably more obj/mtl oriented question (what a pity there is no equivalent of this page for the Wavefront OBJ). Anyway, my main problem/concern is really the obj file output as I am doing it for usage inside UE4, but now I have some suspicion that transparent png are probably not supported in Wavefront OBJ files, but that is a question for somewhere else which i have to find where (to ask it). Well, at least you teached me how to use NODES and how to work with them, so thanks anyway. Still, I flag this as right answer as it make the image tran.

Comment: It looks like the result is not the one you want but I can't tell you more, are your sure the Obj. file with its Mtl works the way you want in other softwares? Maybe change the title of your question so that it is specifically about Mtl imports in Blender?

Comment: well, that is exactly the thing I am finding about right now: it seems image transparency (map_Kd) is not supported, only opaque, tho using map_d (BW image where black reveals, white hides) do partly the job: with this particular image (the yellow arrow with black lining around it) it makes the bg transparent as expected BUT the black around the arrow makes the red surface completely transparent thus we see inside/thru the brick and the yellow makes the arrow whiteish. I guess I am going to ask this on stackoverflow now...

Comment: I don't really understand all that you say, I can just say that in Blender alpha transparency is ok, it's just that the material is not the one you want, no trace of red color except in the viewport display, so either change your title to make it more accurate, or ask a new question about Obj + Mtl import, or ask on another forum, yes  ;)

Comment: :-) yea, that...problem with me is that I am not a native english speaker so my sentences and expressions look accordingly :-D

Comment: I'm not either, it may be me who don't understand what you say, actually it's more the technical aspect that I don't know (Obj import)

Comment: nevermind, I am still very happy with all your answers regarding Blender so I hope you will answer any of my future questions in that are too :)