# Material Preview as default viewport shading

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way how to set up Material Preview mode as default Viewport Shading, so that everytime I open Blender it would start with that view?

Comment: open Blender, switch to Material preview, go in File > Defaults > Save Startup File

Comment: Yes, that;s it - thank you + pity you did not answer the normal way so I could mark your answer as the correct one, now I do not know how to set this question answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Blender, switch to *Material* preview, go in *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*.

Comment: Now it seems like you are my main "solver of problems". That being said; would you be so kind and look also into this problem here (it looks you have answer for everything Blender-wise): [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195762/imported-obj-file-with-transparent-texture-has-black-background)